# Record WAV from command line, with sound device selection

Tags: windows, audio

I need Windows software to record from a specific sound card for a certain period of time, that can be invoked with command-line parameters.

- SoX would be perfect, except that I cannot select a device on Windows... only OSX.
- VLC may work if I can figure out how to get it to choose a device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I record sound from the windows command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/192327/how-can-i-record-sound-from-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: @Nifle, this is **not** a duplicate... did you even read my question, and the one you linked to?  I need to choose the sound device to record with.  This is makes my question distinct from the question you linked to, as well as the 15 others I found here that are similar.

Comment: Why is this rather important information not in your question?

Comment: You could use [SSD – Set Sound Device](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/quickly-set-sound-device-in-windows-7-from-desktop-or-commandline/) to set your default sound device and then start the recording (all from the command line)

Comment: @Nifle, and to the person who +1 your comment, it **is** part of my question.  The title:  "Record WAV from command line, **with sound device selection**  The first line:  "I need Windows software to **record from a specific sound card**..."  Also, while I appreciate your link to SSD, it does not apply to my situation.  I am trying to record sound, not play it.  SSD only appears to set the playback device.

Comment: What you should have told us is that you had checked out the other answers and that they didn't suit you because of: *Your explanation here*. That way you wouldn't have gotten my close vote. As you'll note you have received no further votes to close after your comment about why the other questions doesn't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution.  It's about a year too late for me, but maybe this will help someone else.

As it turns out, FFMPEG supports DirectShow under Windows, allowing us to select an audio input.  For example, the following command records my web cam's microphone, dumping an MP3 file along the way:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (2- Microsoft LifeCa" test.mp3
```

You can get a list of input devices by running:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

I found this solution while stumbling across a blog entry here:  http://nerdlogger.com/2011/11/03/stream-your-windows-desktop-using-ffmpeg/