# How to record 10 seconds of audio with SoX?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, sox

I want to record 10 seconds of audio from my microphone input with [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net). I haven’t found any example in the documentation or elsewhere that would show how to do it. Here’s my current command using `timeout` to stop the recording. Is there a better way to do it?

```
timeout 10 sox -b 32 -e unsigned-integer -r 96k -c 2 -d --clobber --buffer $((96000*2*10)) /tmp/soxrecording.wav
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A little late, but if anyone had the same question, you have to use the trim "effect" to record a set length of audio.

So to record 10 seconds of audio just append trim 0 10 at the end of your command, e.g.,

```
$ sox -b 32 -e unsigned-integer -r 96k -c 2 -d --clobber --buffer $((96000*2*10)) /tmp/soxrecording.wav trim 0 10
```

From the SoX [man](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html):

> trim {position(+)}
>
> Cuts portions out of the audio. Any number of positions may be given;
>   audio is not sent to the output until the first position is reached.
>   The effect then alternates between copying and discarding audio at
>   each position. Using a value of 0 for the first position parameter
>   allows copying from the beginning of the audio.

Comment: better late than never :)