# Is it possible to record the output of sound in macOS from the Terminal?

Tags: macos, audio, sox

I would like to record the output audio of my Mac to an audio file using the command line, where I can specify the length of time to record.

So for example, I might ask the command to record to a file for 10 seconds. How do I do this? Can it be done using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net)? I’m open to other methods including the use of an API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Soundflower](https://soundflower.en.softonic.com/mac/) to direct the output audio to SoX.

Install Soundflower, then go to “System Preferences > Sound”, and set Soundflower (2ch) as both the output device and input device.
Then record 10 seconds using SoX, e.g. as suggested in [this question and answer thread](https://superuser.com/questions/889912/how-to-record-10-seconds-of-audio-with-sox).

To switch to Soundflower as output/input device (and back) you can use the [switchaudio-osx](https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx) tool, which you can install via Homebrew.

Use the commands:

```
SwitchAudioSource -s 'Soundflower (2ch)' -t 'output'
SwitchAudioSource -s 'Soundflower (2ch)' -t 'input'
```

Using Soundflower, SoX, and switchaudio-osx together, it should be possible to write a script to do the whole process, with an argument for specifying the length of the recording.