# How to record 30 seconds of audio from the iOS simulator with sox (or equivalent)?

Tags: macos, audio, audio-recording, sox

I want to record 30 seconds of audio from the iOS simulator on OSX.

I have found an example to record audio using a microphone.
[How to record 10 seconds of audio with SoX?](https://superuser.com/questions/889912/how-to-record-10-seconds-of-audio-with-sox)

However I need to capture the sound from the iOS simulator.

I'm guessing here that soundflower may be required, however I'm not sure how to specify the source.