# How to start Windows Voice Recorder from the cmd?

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 and I need a way to launch the Windows Voice Recorder from the cmd line.

How can I do it ?

With the old SoundRecorder, I use this command:

```
"soundrecorder /FILE c:\temp\output.wav /DURATION 0:0:10"
```

Comment: HTH: http://superuser.com/questions/192327/how-can-i-record-sound-from-the-windows-command-line

Answer (score 3):

To lauch the Soundrecorder app of Windows 10 run this command:

```
explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```